# How to remove from JSOn based on attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have got a JSON as follows

```
[{
        "name": "Mike",
        "incentives": "23.45"
    },
    {
        "name": "Larsen",
        "incentives": "34.78",
        "newlyadded": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Steve",
        "incentives": "26.78"
    }
]
```

I need to remove all the JSON Objects which contains the attribute as **newlyadded**

i tried it this way

```
myjson = myjson.filter((obj) => myjson.indexOf(obj.newlyadded) === true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/54476/

Could you please tell me how to make this work

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `obj.newlyadded` to be missing or false, because `.filter` leaves only values that return true.

```js
var myjson = [{
  "name": "Mike",
  "incentives": "23.45"
 },
 {
  "name": "Larsen",
  "incentives": "34.78",
  "newlyadded": true
 },
 {
  "name": "Steve",
  "incentives": "26.78"
 }
];

myjson = myjson.filter((obj) => typeof obj.newlyadded === 'undefined' || obj.newlyadded !== true);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myjson))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
 more details on [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 
 var myjson = [{
  "name": "Mike",
  "incentives": "23.45"
 },
 {
  "name": "Larsen",
  "incentives": "34.78",
  "newlyadded": true
 },
 {
  "name": "Steve",
  "incentives": "26.78"
 }
];



json = myjson.filter((obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('newlyadded') === false);

console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```